How to remove loose edges in geometry nodes
I followed this tutorial to make some kind of fungal growth thing. I want to remesh the end result to look like a blobby mass. The problem is, this setup leaves loose edges behind which ruin the remesh. Is there a quick way to delete them with some node? Or is it somehow possible to make the remesh modifier ignore loose edges. Either way would work for me. Here is the .blend file (2.1mb)

A setup like this works for me.


